# Do we say "Do you remember your homework?" or "Did you remember your homework?"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, past-tense, present-tense

I agree that we should say "**I remembered my homework**" because at the time I say this sentence I have already remembered it.

I am not sure if we can say "**I remember my homework**" because I did remember it before I say.

Is it logical to say "**Do you remember your homework?**"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on which of the rather different meanings of *remember* you intend.

*Do you remember your homework?* normally means something like "Can you bring to mind the content of your homework, or what you wrote in your homework?", and suggests that we are discuss what your homework was about, or required you to do.

*Did you remember your homework?* normally means "Did you remember to bring your homework home?" or "Did you remember to do your homework?" - about what you did, not about the content of the homework.

I'll expand on this a little. With most verbs, we use *do you ... ?* only in a habitual sense. One exception is verbs of perception and inner state: *do you think*, *do you see*, *do you feel*. Thus, unless there is a context which makes a habitual reading plausible. *do you remember ...?* is asking about your inner perception, and hence about whether you remember facts or an experience.

*Did you remember* **could** also have that meaning, but would be talking about a past time - whether at that time you remembered (facts or experiences).

But *remember* in the sense of *remember to do something* is not a verb of perception or experience.

Comment: Another (and probably more idiomatic at the beginning of term) meaning for the first example: are you the sort of person who diligently does their homework each night? - given that remember essentially means 'remember to do' not 'keep in mind.'